# How do I install a SQL Server on the hosted build agent in Visual Studio Online?

Tags: sql-server, unit-testing, tfs, tfsbuild, azure-devops

One of our customers uses Visual Studio Online ( http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/what-is-visual-studio-online-vs.aspx ) which is based on capabilities of Team Foundation Server (TFS)

We were researching how to do automated Builds and automated Unit Tests using the Visual Studio Online account.

Using Visual Studio 2012 IDE, I was able to setup a build in the Hosted Build Service. However, my Unit Tests need a Microsoft SQL Server Database to run properly, which I have installed on my development workstation.

In order to run my tests I need to have my database running in a SQL instance on the build agent.

Is it possible to install SQL server on the Hosted Build Agent, and if so, how?

Comment: @ed-Blankenship Hey, could you please respond to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27705432/steps-to-install-microsoft-sql-server-database-on-a-visual-studio-online-account  ?

Comment: if you need an actual database up and running for your tests to work then they ain't unit tests. They are integration tests.

Comment: You should try to re-write your Integration Tests to be Unit Tests by mocking the database and removing the need to have an instance.

Comment: You could start an install at the beginning of your build sequence but it will end up eating time during every build since the build server is re-imaged each time.  Why not have a SQL Azure database spun up during each build or host the SQL database on another server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your help.

I contacted @tamasf who is one of the developers for the Effort Testing Tool for Entity Framework, and he told me that Effort Testing Tool only needs to know about he EDMX file in order mock Entity Framework ( which means Database won't need to be up and running, therefore, allowing us to follow proper Unit testing practices )  For more information, please read the following post: [How would I configure Effort Testing Tool to mock Entity Framework's DbContext withOut the actual SQL Server Database up and running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27716714/how-would-i-configure-effort-testing-tool-to-mock-entity-frameworks-dbcontext-w)

Answer (score 6):

**It is not possible to add non-standard capabilities to a hosted build agent.** You are assigned a clean pre-built VM with all of the standard pre-requisite for compiling binaries and running unit tests. As integration tests, what you are describing above, require an instance of your application you can't run them there.

Here are the options that you have in order of recommendation:

## 1 - Re-write your tests as Unit and not Integration

The tests that you are describing above do not meet the standard definition of "[Unit Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing)". You can use mocking, stubs, and other testing techniques to decouple your tests from the database so that they are only testing a **single unit** of functionality rather than the **integration between** your code and the database. Having sets of tests for each will better help you isolate the route cause of the issue and more quickly fix it at less cost to your customer. It will also aid in the reduction of bugs and other issues that can be introduced over time.

Large complicated integration tests should be kept to a minimum as it increases the amount of time required to support them and maximises the cost to your customer.

One obviously needs integration tests at some point and option #2 is the best for running integrations.

## 2 - Use Release Management to deploy and test

You can setup a VM to host a working version of your application and use Release Management to deploy the instance then execute your Integration Tests there. If you use the VSO hosted Release Management server you are limited to Azure VM's as targets. If you deploy your own RM server then you need to manage that as well. I would and do use the hosted RM.

[image: DevOps release pipeline with TFS and VSO]

The bit we care about is the DevOps bit on the right. Any time you need an instance of your application it should be deployed correctly separately from your build server.

http://nakedalm.com/create-release-management-pipeline-professional-developers/

Once you have your application deployed it is fairly simple to get the integration tests you want executing against the instance.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/11/11/deploying-and-testing-web-applications-using-release-management.aspx

If you download the example from the link above it has a powershell for executing the tests in the environment.

## 3 - Setup your own agent and controller

You can create your own build controller & agent attached to the VSO account and build the app yourself. Most folks create an Azure VM with all of the bits they need and run there. This is your server that you will need to manage and pay for. You can also use a local server.

*Note: This is the wrong approach as an instance of your application should not be available on a build server. A build server is for compiling your binaries and running actual Unit Tests, not integration or UI tests.*

Comment: I started Using Effort Testing Tool for Entity Framework to mock DBContext. Previously, I was using Moq Framework, but Moq needs be instructed and configured quite a bit of work if you want Moq to mock Entity Framework's DbContext.  Effort Testing Tool can easily mock EF's DbContext, but I believe that Effort Testing Tool needs the SQL Server Database up and running in order to create an in-memory version of the SQL Server Database.

Comment: "The tests that you are describing above do not meet the standard definition of Unit Test" - who cares. Testing with a real database is a valid approach.